# "Sorry, can you please just move away?"

Tags: expressions

Today I went to the coffee shop and someone asked me "Sorry, can you please just move away?" because I was standing by the trash can and she was trying to throw out something. I just felt that there is a better way to ask about this and this sounded kind of rude to me. Is it legitimate for me to feel offended or is it just a colloquial expression?

Comment: "Just" definitely shows irritation, it should be omitted for politeness' sake. "Move away" is also rude.  But at least they said "Sorry". They could have simply said: "Sorry, could I throw this to the bin, please?" Anyone would understand and move away.

Comment: could you suggest any way to respond to this? I didn't say anything at the moment, but what do you think I should have done?

Comment: This is off-topic, as it does not concern English language per se. Depends on your character.

Comment: Yes. I just thought it's just a cultural thing. But thanks for your response :)

Comment: Have a look at the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site. You will understand why this question is rather off-topic here.

Comment: At the moment, avoidable blocking off of people from legitimate destinations (getting past on the pavement, accessing a door / counter / bin ...) is especially inconsiderate. Yes, the request should have been more polite, but 'Sorry' covers the first offence.

Comment: The correcting word was *aside*. Move away is *get lost* in AE. Move aside means a foot or so to the side, not an admonition to you but a small request for clearance for the pitch. An adult need not take great offense caused by inconsolable pain from an unprepared bossiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that a more polite formulation could have been used, although it is anybody's guess whether the person was intentionally rude or was just in rush and couldn't think of a better way to formulate the request. The following features of the formulation make it less polite than it (arguably) should have been.

**(1)** The use of *could* rather than *can* would have been an easy way to make it clear that this is a polite request, rather than an expression of annoyance at one's being there at all (*can* arguably implicates that the only legitimate reason for one's standing there is that one is unable to move).

**(2)** *Just* implies that moving is a simple and obvious thing to do, which may be taken to suggest that one should have already done it, which also contributes to the formulation appearing to be an expression of annoyance.

**(3)** Normally, when one asks a stranger to do something, one shows respect by offering some reason for the request; the fact that this wasn't done in this case, again, makes the request less polite than it should have been.